# Grails 3 - Alternative to @Rollback in Integration tests

Tags: hibernate, grails, junit, grails-3.0

**Short version:** I am looking for a way to attach the hibernate session to the integration test thread with auto-commit (Grails 2.x behavior).

I am converting a plugin to Grails 3.0.11.  Things are more or less progressing, but I found a problem with GUI testing (using Geb/JUnit).  I have work-arounds, but they are somewhat ugly.

The Grails docs say to use @Rollback to get hibernate access in your tests.  The problem is that the test can no longer commit changes to the records for the GUI to process.  This is somewhat critical for GUI tests to see the data we create in the test itself.

So, I remove @Rollback and then I get the Hibernate exception about no session assigned to the thread:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
```

My first fix is to wrap the DB access withTransaction:

```
User.withTransaction {
  domain.save()
}
```

This will commit the data, but it seems like a lot of work.  I do a bit of setup of data in the GUI tests and verify that they work with Geb/JUnit.

I then added *@Transactional* to the top of the test class.  That seemed to work, but does it not commit until the test is done. So, I added   *@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)* for the setup method.  Again, a little bit of rework.

Is there any way to associate a hibernate session with the JUnit test itself and with commit possible?  I want a way to attach the hibernate session to the integration test thread with auto-commit (Grails 2.x behavior).

I guess I could get the auto-commit with some H2 JDBC option.

**Edit**:

I decided to go with a mixture of *@Transactional* (class level), *@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)* at the method level and sometimes *Domain.withTransaction {}*.

Sometimes, a method level *@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)* will let me do a *Domain.withTransaction {}* approach within a single method.

It really is a mis-mash of various strategies.  No simple global setting.  It was some much simpler before (I even wondered how Grails 2.x dealt with transactions in the GUI tests.  Now, I suspect they just auto-committed everything :).